# What variant of interaction when the PH assumption is violated in a CoxPH Model?

Tags: interaction, cox-model, proportional-hazards

When the assumption of proportional hazards is violated, the suggestion is to interact offending covariates with time (or a function of time). In [this blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dealing-with-non-proportional-hazards-in-r/), the author suggests to include only the interaction effects without the main effects by opting for the ":" variant instead of the "*" variant when fitting `coxph`. Does that make sense to you? If so, it would be great if you could explain.

Comment: Take good care **NOT** to model interaction with final survival time! Time-varying effects need to be modelled with the 'internal time'. See my answer here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286595/time-dependent-coefficients-in-cox-regression-cph-rms/287741#287741) how to handle this in R and how such an 'internal time' variable would look like.

Comment: Thanks, I did. I think what you are suggesting is synonymous to what the blog post's author refers to when he talks about splitting survival times up and interacting only with the start time.

Comment: I see, that would be fine. Whether or not to model using ":" (colon), or "*" is also in the blogpost: "we will therefore add a time interaction using the ':' variant (note using the '*' for interactions gives a separate variable for the time and that is not of interest in this case)"

Comment: In your model, you also just include interactions without main effects if I am not mistaken. Was there any reasoning behind that? Edit: Yes, it is in the blog post, but I don't understand the underlying rationale.

Comment: The thing is you do not want a separate time effect, you only want the effect of covariate $i$ to change with time. The separate time variable using an asterix would result in, is not required. Using a colon (in R) solves this by only using the multiplication of the covariate and the 'start time' variable in a split up survival dataset

Comment: Thanks. I now see that the author does actually include main effects of the covariate and the interaction and just omits the main effect of time (which makes sense to me now). In your linked post, should it then not say: fit.long<-cph(Surv(tstart,time,status)~ph.karno+ph.karnologtime + age,x=T,y=T,data=lung.long)?

Comment: you're right, I've edited the answer.

Comment: For Stata users, let me also recommend this useful user-written command: https://github.com/anddis/stphcoxrcs